# Meaning of "As" in the sentence, "As is usual in this kind of movie,~"?

Tags: conjunctions, subjects

What is the meaning of "As" in the sentence, "As is usual in this kind of movie, good triumphs over evil in the end" ?

Dose "As" is the subject in the sentence, "As is usual in this kind of movie" ?

Does "As" mean "it" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is *good.*

One way to find the subject is to ask, Who or what is doing something? In this case, *good* is doing something. It *triumphs.*

In the sentence, *as* means *like*:

> Like usual in this kind of movie, good triumphs over evil in the end.

Here is a corresponding dictionary definition and example.

*adverb*
4.
in the manner (directed, agreed, promised, etc.):
*She sang as promised. He left as agreed.*

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as

Comment: IF as mean like,  why the "as" is followed by the verb "is" ? may i write "As  usual in this kind of movie" instead of "As is usual in this kind of movie" ?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, "as" is being used in the simile

> As is usual in this kind of movie
>   *(in this movie) as is usual in this kind of movie*

"in this movie" is implicit.

Similes are comparisons using "as" or "like"

> this movie as in other movies of this kind
>   this movie like other movies of this kind

The author is also using "as is" to say

> as is usual in this kind movie
>   *as is (the) usual (case) in this kind of movie*

> *(in this movie)* as is *(the)* usual *(case)* in this kind of movie